# Let $(0,3)\rightarrow S^1$ be a map such that $x\in (0,3)\rightarrow e^{2\pi i x}$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Let $(0,3)\rightarrow S^1$ be a map such that $x\in (0,3)\rightarrow e^{2\pi i x}$.

Is this a covering?

Comment: It can't be since $\;S^1\;$ is closed and bounded (in fact, compact), whereas $\;(0,3)\;$ isn't...

Comment: Hint: Look carefully at the definition of _evenly-covered_ in open neighborhoods of the images of the endpoints of the interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f$ denote your map. If it were a covering, then all fibers $f^{-1}(z)$ would have the same cardinality because $S^1$ is connected. But $f^{-1}(1) = \mathbb Z \cap (0,3) = \{1,2\}$ and $f^{-1}(-1) = \{n + 1/2 \mid n \in \mathbb Z \} \cap (0,3) = \{1/2, 3/2, 5/2 \}$.

Note that $f$ is a surjective local homeomorphism.

Comment: Thank you @Paul